# This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type unit because it is in the result of a conditional with no else branch

Tags: ocaml

Thank you for reading this question. In my OCaml code, I wrote a function to retrieve the max `object_` from my `heap list`:

```
type object_ = int;;

let rec get_current_heap_max_object (heap1:heap) (acc:object_) = 
  match heap1 with 
  | [] -> acc 
  | hd :: tl -> 
    match hd with 
    | ((obj1, field1), tva1) -> 
      (if acc < obj1 then 
         acc = obj1; 
         get_current_heap_max_object tl acc 
       else 
         get_current_heap_max_object tl acc)
```

The error is at `acc = obj1;` as:

> `This expression has type bool but an expression was expected of type unit because it is in the result of a conditional with no else branch`

Comment: In addition to the answer @octachron posted, a note on OCaml style: a `match` with only one pattern is unnecessary. You ould simply have matched the `((obj1, field1), tva1)` pattern in the first pattern match. `| ((obj1, field1), tva1) :: tl -> ...`

Comment: It was as suggestion for improvement, not a criticism. Or, if criticism, _constructive_ criticism. Eliminating unnecessary code often makes code easier to read and debug. Further, you could even get rid of the if/else and use `when ` guards on your pattern matching to streamline your code.

Comment: OK! Thank you for your help. It is good for me to learn and to follow the professional coding behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression

```ml
if acc < obj1 then acc = obj1
```

the subexpression `acc = obj1` is testing for the equality of `acc` and `obj1`, not assigning a value to the variable `acc` (Variables are immutable by default in OCaml). Since the `then` branch is returning a boolean value, you cannot elide the `else` branch.
You can rewrite your code to avoid relying mutability by defining a new `max` variable which is either `acc` or `obj1`:

```ml
let max = if acc < obj1 then ... else ... in
get_current_heap_max_object tl max
```

Comment: Thank you octachron. I modified my code into: let rec get_current_heap_max_object (heap1:heap) (acc:object_) = match heap1 with 
    | [] -> acc 
    | hd :: tl -> match hd with 
        | ((obj1, field1),tva1) -> (let acc = if acc < obj1 then obj1
            else 
            acc
            in get_current_heap_max_object tl acc)